# Attempt to define a second primary key with IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: h2

Why is this statement failing despite the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause?

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Attempt to define a second primary key; SQL statement:

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_CALENDARS
    ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS PK_QRTZ_CALENDARS PRIMARY KEY ( SCHED_NAME, CALENDAR_NAME ) [90017-212]
```

H2 is run in memory mode `jdbc:h2:mem:quartz;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:tables_h2.sql'`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_CALENDARS (
                                SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                CALENDAR IMAGE NOT NULL
);
```

If I move the PK definition into table definition the error goes away.

The script is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_CALENDARS (
                                SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                CALENDAR IMAGE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS (
                                    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                    CRON_EXPRESSION VARCHAR (120)  NOT NULL ,
                                    TIME_ZONE_ID VARCHAR (80)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (
                                     SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                     ENTRY_ID VARCHAR (95)  NOT NULL ,
                                     TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                     TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                     INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                     FIRED_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                                     SCHED_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                                     PRIORITY INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                                     STATE VARCHAR (16)  NOT NULL,
                                     JOB_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NULL ,
                                     JOB_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NULL ,
                                     IS_NONCONCURRENT BOOLEAN  NULL ,
                                     REQUESTS_RECOVERY BOOLEAN  NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS (
                                          SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                          TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE (
                                      SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                      INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                      LAST_CHECKIN_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                                      CHECKIN_INTERVAL BIGINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_LOCKS (
                            SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                            LOCK_NAME VARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS (
                                  SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                  JOB_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                  JOB_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (250) NULL ,
                                  JOB_CLASS_NAME VARCHAR (250)  NOT NULL ,
                                  IS_DURABLE BOOLEAN  NOT NULL ,
                                  IS_NONCONCURRENT BOOLEAN  NOT NULL ,
                                  IS_UPDATE_DATA BOOLEAN  NOT NULL ,
                                  REQUESTS_RECOVERY BOOLEAN  NOT NULL ,
                                  JOB_DATA IMAGE NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS (
                                      SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                      TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                      TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                      REPEAT_COUNT BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                                      REPEAT_INTERVAL BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                                      TIMES_TRIGGERED BIGINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS (
                                       SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                       TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                                       TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                                       STR_PROP_1 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
                                       STR_PROP_2 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
                                       STR_PROP_3 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
                                       INT_PROP_1 INTEGER NULL,
                                       INT_PROP_2 INTEGER NULL,
                                       LONG_PROP_1 BIGINT NULL,
                                       LONG_PROP_2 BIGINT NULL,
                                       DEC_PROP_1 NUMERIC(13,4) NULL,
                                       DEC_PROP_2 NUMERIC(13,4) NULL,
                                       BOOL_PROP_1 BOOLEAN NULL,
                                       BOOL_PROP_2 BOOLEAN NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS (
                                    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                                    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                                    BLOB_DATA IMAGE NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_TRIGGERS (
                               SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                               TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                               TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                               JOB_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                               JOB_GROUP VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
                               DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (250) NULL ,
                               NEXT_FIRE_TIME BIGINT NULL ,
                               PREV_FIRE_TIME BIGINT NULL ,
                               PRIORITY INTEGER NULL ,
                               TRIGGER_STATE VARCHAR (16)  NOT NULL ,
                               TRIGGER_TYPE VARCHAR (8)  NOT NULL ,
                               START_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                               END_TIME BIGINT NULL ,
                               CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NULL ,
                               MISFIRE_INSTR SMALLINT NULL ,
                               JOB_DATA IMAGE NULL
);

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_CALENDARS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_CALENDARS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         CALENDAR_NAME
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         ENTRY_ID
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         INSTANCE_NAME
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_LOCKS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         LOCK_NAME
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         JOB_NAME,
         JOB_GROUP
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_TRIGGERS  ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  PK_QRTZ_TRIGGERS PRIMARY KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            );

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  FK_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS FOREIGN KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            ) REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (
                                        SCHED_NAME,
                                        TRIGGER_NAME,
                                        TRIGGER_GROUP
            ) ON DELETE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  FK_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS FOREIGN KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            ) REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (
                                        SCHED_NAME,
                                        TRIGGER_NAME,
                                        TRIGGER_GROUP
            ) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  FK_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS FOREIGN KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         TRIGGER_NAME,
         TRIGGER_GROUP
            ) REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (
                                        SCHED_NAME,
                                        TRIGGER_NAME,
                                        TRIGGER_GROUP
            ) ON DELETE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE QRTZ_TRIGGERS ADD
    CONSTRAINT  IF NOT EXISTS  FK_QRTZ_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS FOREIGN KEY
        (
         SCHED_NAME,
         JOB_NAME,
         JOB_GROUP
            ) REFERENCES QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS (
                                           SCHED_NAME,
                                           JOB_NAME,
                                           JOB_GROUP
            );

COMMIT;
```

**The error only happens when concurrent connections are established**.

If I set the pool size to 1 it does not occur.
If I set the pool size to 2 I see it logged once.
If I set the pool size to 3 I see it logged twice.

The error seems to be gone when the connection pool retries.

It all looks like a concurrency bug in H2

Answer (score 2):

`IF NOT EXISTS` checks only presence of constraint with exactly the same name. This exception indicates that your table already has a primary key constraint with the same or other set of columns, but with different name.

If you're sure that this table either has a primary key constraint on these two columns with unknown name or doesn't have a primary key constraint at all, you can replace your command with the following one:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'QRTZ_CALENDARS' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')
THEN 'ALTER TABLE QRTZ_CALENDARS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_QRTZ_CALENDARS PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, CALENDAR_NAME)'
ELSE ''
END;
```

Comment: No, actually I'm sure it's not defined there

Comment: This exception clearly indicates that your table already has a primary key constraint, for example, if this table was defined as `CREATE TABLE QRTZ_CALENDARS(ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, SCHED_NAME VARCHAR, …`), it has a PK constraint on `ID` column with auto-generated name. Please, add definition of your table to the question. Maybe you need to create a unique constraint instead.

Comment: Your script has a stray comma in definition `qrtz_simprop_triggers` on the line 95, with this comma removed it can be executed without any errors in a new empty database. On the line 124 it creates a PK constraint `PK_QRTZ_CALENDARS` in your table. Are you sure that you use this script to populate a new database? It cannot be executed as is due to mentioned syntax error.

Comment: I corrected the comma before executing the script. I think this might be a bug in H2, see latest edit

Comment: I can not reproduce this 100% with in-memory database. Meaning no previous state.